# 3-column layout with max height columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create page with following layout:
[image: desired layout]

- page occupies entire viewport: `html, body {height: 100%}`
- `#header` is on the top of the page with `height: 80px`
- actual page content (`#content`) takes all remaining space and divided into 3 columns with margins

For columns I'm using bootstrap's `.row-fluid` with `span-X` children.

If I use `position: static` for `#header` and set `height: 100%` to `#content` page will have height more than viewport by 80px.

If I set `#header`'s position using `position: absolute` and add some element before `#content` with `height: 80px` then page will be larger than viewport by 80px. I tried to set margins and paddings to `#content` instead of adding the empty element, but this didn't helped.

Comment: Note: Clicking on "following layout" will cause a `.png` to download.

Comment: please include your html and css. its hard to help you without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your `header` before `content` and give it `width:100%; height:80px; position:absolute;` and giving `.column{margin-top: 85px;}`will do something similar to what you were looking for.
**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Cnfr/4/)**

`<html>`

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content">
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```

`<style>`

```
#header{
width:100%;
height:80px;    
background:red;
position:absolute;

}

#content{

width:100%;
height:100%;    
background:blue;

}
.column{
margin-top: 85px;
float: left;
position: relative;
width: 20%;
margin-left: 95px;
background: #FF0;
height: 75%;
}

html{height:100%;}
body{height: 100%;
margin: 0;}
```

Comment: And how to assign remaining height to `content`?

Comment: In your fiddle page height larger by 80px than viewport.

Comment: if you can use jquery/Javascript, than you can always recalculate height of objects

Comment: last fiddle looks like what I need. Can you update the answer and set html's height as 100%?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent overflow, try to put both the `#header` and the `#content` in a `#container` and give the container a `height: 100%`.

But to fill the entire page from top to bottom, you might want to experiment with `display: flex` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes or `.parent { display: table;} .child {display: table-cell;}`

Comment: In this case I have to somehow assing all remaining vertical space to `#content`. If I set it to 100% I'll get 80px "scroller". Actually the `#container` is the same as `body`.

Comment: But personally, I think it is always a bad idea to mix fluid and static layout in this way. A lot better idea would be to give the header a `height: 20%;` and the content `height: 80%;`

Comment: Ahh, I see, you are trying to fill the entire viewport, not just to prevent overflow